# Convert Word Art to Text (MS OFFICE WORD)

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there any way to convert Word Art to text in Microsoft office, the same way you can convert text to WordArt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting text to WordArt actually inserts the current text in a floating text box with some fancy styles. The inverse conversion is not unambiguous, though, as the text in the floating blocks will lose the absolute positioning info for the floating blocks - e.g. the text is docked 100 px below a specified paragraph, so it appears as part of the next paragraph (actually floating in the middle of the next paragraph flow).

You can however run a macro that will convert all such blocks to text and see if the result would work for you, for example like in the [Removing All Text Boxes In a Document](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T009169_Removing_All_Text_Boxes_In_a_Document.html) article:

```vb
Sub RemoveTextBox2()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim oRngAnchor As Range
    Dim sString As String

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            ' copy text to string, without last paragraph mark
            sString = Left(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, _
              shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count - 1)
            If Len(sString) > 0 Then
                ' set the range to insert the text
                Set oRngAnchor = shp.Anchor.Paragraphs(1).Range
                ' insert the textbox text before the range object
                oRngAnchor.InsertBefore _
                  "Textbox start << " & sString & " >> Textbox end"
            End If
            shp.delete
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

This basically iterates over all text boxes, gets their text, insert it in the document, and then removes the text boxes.